# Insert proc failing even though we check exists first

Tags: t-sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spWeb_TransactionProjectUpdate]
    @transactionId              INT,
    @projectId                  INT
AS

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.com_project_transaction_link WHERE pt_tr_transaction_id = @transactionId AND pt_pj_project_id = @projectId)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.com_project_transaction_link(pt_tr_transaction_id, pt_pj_project_id) VALUES (@transactionId, @projectId)

END
```

So when we run this with after an identical record is already in the database, it fails. But we have the `IF NOT EXISTS` there for this exact reason. Why would it be trying to insert if it finds a record?

Comment: Are you sure you are not passing a `NULL` value on one of those parameters?

Comment: positive. it's acting really strange

Comment: That is quite strange. No pending transactions on that table?

Comment: I think it might have to do with the concurrent stuff that i see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that pair of columns `(pt_tr_transaction_id, pt_pj_project_id)` is unique, why not just put a UNIQUE INDEX on these two columns? Combine this with the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option on that index, and you would have an index that

- prevents any duplicates from being inserted
- doesn't barf (throw exception) when a duplicate is encountered - it's just being swallowed silently

This check of yours is prone to failure, since you're not doing anything to prevent two clients to running at the same time; both could first check to see if that row exists and get back a `false`, and then both could proceed to insert those values. The check you have is not safe against concurrent execution.